# Insert separator between elements in the result string

Tags: jquery

I want to reuse breadcrumbs structure for a friendly SEO category header. How can I get separator (/) in the output using `.text()` function?

Thanks in advance!

```js
$(function(){
    var str = $( ".breadcrumb-element").text();
    $( "p.text22" ) .html( str );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="breadcrumb">
    <a class="breadcrumb-element" href="#" title="Go to Sale">Sale</a>
    <a class="breadcrumb-element" href="#" title="Go to Accessories">Accessories</a>
    <a class="breadcrumb-element" href="#" title="Go to Scarves">Scarves</a>
</div>

<br><br><br><br>

<p class="text22"></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a function in `.text()` to check the index of the element and if its not the 1st element, insert a `/` in front of the text.

```
$( ".breadcrumb-element").text(function(i, t){
str += i == 0 ? t : '/' + t;
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64z5t05u/)

```js
var str = '';
$( ".breadcrumb-element").text(function(i, t){
str += i == 0 ? t : '/' + t;
});
$( "p.text22" ) .html( str );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="breadcrumb">
<a class="breadcrumb-element" href="#" title="Go to Sale">Sale</a>
<a class="breadcrumb-element" href="#" title="Go to Accessories">Accessories</a>
<a class="breadcrumb-element" href="#" title="Go to Scarves">Scarves</a>
</div>


<br><br><br><br>

<p class="text22"></p>
```

Comment: Many thanks Pat! This version is very close to the ideal one. It will be great to have in <p class="text22"></p> only the text with separator without links.

Comment: I just checked the script on staging and it removes my original breadcrubs.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is something for CSS.
Just define :after pseudo element to display the delimiter.

**Example:**

```
.breadcrumb-element:after {
  content: '/';
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumb-element:last-child:after {
  content: '';
}
```

Using JS for this is little bit bloated. But just my 5 cents.

```css
.breadcrumb-element {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.breadcrumb-element:after {
  content: '/';
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.breadcrumb-element:last-child:after {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div class="breadcrumb">
<a class="breadcrumb-element" href="#" title="Go to Sale">Sale</a>
<a class="breadcrumb-element" href="#" title="Go to Accessories">Accessories</a>
<a class="breadcrumb-element" href="#" title="Go to Scarves">Scarves</a>
</div>


<br><br><br><br>

<p class="text22"></p>
```